# Block specific File Uploads in Legacy ASP sites

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, iis-7, http-post, iis-8

I am working with a huge number of vulnerable classic asp sites involving uploading files.

We need to prevent specific uploads from being uploaded ".exe, .asp, .aspx, etc etc"

However we would ideally like to not have to fix these huge code bases (many many sites).

So I am trying to come up with a good way to block file uploads of specific types globally to the whole box.

I've come up with a few,

1. File System Watcher
2. Block Get Requests on X Folder, allow uploads (write access) only to X folder "not universal to all sites"
3. Come up with a way to intercept asp requests, analyze them, and block or pass them on to the ISAPI ASP Handler.

The file system watcher is a good idea, but I've read it can be unreliable, and it would be running on hundreds of folders on 1 machine.  It would need to be fast enough to delete a bad upload before the uploader can do a get request on it.

2 is probably the best solution, but many sites have wildcard upload locations "upload anywhere in the site root" so wouldn't work for those.  If I turned off get requests on the root the site breaks.

3 sounds plausible, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

If I can make my own HttpHandler in c# with .Net and register it to *.asp and put it in the web config before the Classic ASP handler, it will fire for ASP requests instead.

At which point I can check if the post type is a Post, and if it has a file, and if that file is allowed.

If it checks out, then I would need to pass that request to the original handler.

Anyone got any better ideas or know if #3 is possible?

Update: Our firewall cannot block asp or aspx uploads, and I was unable to find a way to do it in Windows Firewall either.

Comment: Are you using a class or a third party component to do your uploads?

Comment: @John the uploads are done with asp pages, form elements, and inputs with file upload types.  Full page post back, old school, traditional uploads.

The code that does this is everywhere, in hundreds of different versions in hundreds of different revisions and instances.  Otherwise I would just find the code, add code to block the uploads there, and be done with it.  We will be phasing the code out over time, but we need an immediate quick (hacky) solution that let's us turn uploads back on asap. Write now I have disabled write access to everything.

Comment: I know #2 works well, but with that I only turn uploads on, on some of the sites, still 20% or so that solution won't work for.

Comment: Ok, so I am writing an ISAP Filter in C++ with Visual Studio 2015 to do this, will post some info if it works.  I tried doing it with an HttpModule, but if you touch an ASP request with .Net Request objects it messes with it, and that breaks classic asp when it finally get's the request.

Comment: No go on the isapi filter, IIS7/8 don't support the the SF_NOTIFY_READ_RAW_DATA notification so I can't see the request body to analyze the file names.  I have moved onto native iis7 apis and a native HttpModule, will give that a whirl.